# Ubuntu Randomly Rejecting Hosts

Tags: 12.04, networking, server, firewall

currently I am facing a very strange problem: my Ubuntu is randomly resetting connections and I have no clue why.

/etc/hosts.deny is empty (resp. just the default file with comments only, that comes with ubuntu)

I already purged ufw off the system and IPtables is set to ACCEPT everything:

```
root@Template-Ubuntu-12:~# iptables -L -v
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT 43 packets, 6118 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT 16 packets, 1520 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
```

This is my current release:

```
root@Template-Ubuntu-12:~# uname -a
Linux Template-Ubuntu-12 3.13.0-27-generic #50~precise1-Ubuntu SMP Fri May 16 20:47:56 UTC 2014 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Here is an example - suddenly in the middle of typing something in an ssh session I get disconnected:

```
tzhwiman@Template-Ubuntu-12:~$ u[LOCAL] : Stream has closed [CLOSE_TYPE_NONSPECIFIC] : Connection was reset. 
[LOCAL] : Changing state from STATE_CONNECTION to STATE_CLOSED 
[LOCAL] : Discarding invalid state change from STATE_CLOSED to STATE_ALMOST_CLOSED. 
[LOCAL] : Connected for 331 seconds, 1819 bytes sent, 3713 bytes received 

Connection was reset.
```

Also I'm not able to reconnect for a random amount of time. BUT: I can login from another source without any problems.

I also found that I can recover connectivity if I login from another host/source and then ping the host that is currently blocked (note that when a host is blocked always the first few pings get lost):

```
PING X.X.126.19 (X.X.126.19) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from X.X.126.19: icmp_req=2 ttl=128 time=0.526 ms
64 bytes from X.X.126.19: icmp_req=3 ttl=128 time=0.499 ms
64 bytes from X.X.126.19: icmp_req=4 ttl=128 time=0.459 ms
^C
--- X.X.126.19 ping statistics ---
4 packets transmitted, 3 received, 25% packet loss, time 2999ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 0.459/0.494/0.526/0.037 ms
```

Strange enough ping(icmp) from the host that is blocked (to the ubuntu) is always working, but I cannot connect to ssh (port 22) nor to the webserver (port 80). I analyzed the traffic and for each tcp SYN I immediately get a tcp RST.

Where can I check/debug more?  I already had a look at /var/log/syslog  auth.log kern.log but I couldn't find anything suspicious

Comment: Check your network connection (including local infrastructure) first. Easiest way is to use another device and leave a ping going. Use the same cable if you're using one.

Comment: my network connection is fine. I can access everything else without issues/connection resets or similar

Comment: I once had something like this when there was another device on the network claiming to own my IP and the switch didn't know which to trust, causing huge packet loss. Just rolling ideas around.

Comment: Hi Oli, thanks for the hint, I think you're right I was just checking the arp tables on the blocked host and comparing to ifconfig on the server - seems like there's a duplicate IP somewhere in the lan. I'll update as soon as I can confirm